# I removed Python 3.4 physically, is there anything I can do to avoid having to reinstall system?

Tags: apt, system-installation, software-installation, python3

While trying to install a python package I made a horrible mistake and removed Python 3.4 (if you are interested in how did I come up with it below is the link to my question on StackOverflow).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426547/physically-uninstalled-python-3-4-to-make-pip3-install-requests-package-to-pyt/36426985?noredirect=1#comment60469836_36426985

Anyway, now I can't run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.4`, which is pretty bad I guess. Is there any way I could make my ubuntu 14.04 work again without having to lose files on my computer?

EDIT: Btw. I still have Python 2.7 (which I thought was the one used by the system), perhaps there is some way to use it to recover the rest?

Comment: Is python still linked to python2.7? `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` It may be you just need to do install, not reinstall as it now is gone? It used to be that deleting any python damaged system so much reinstall was the only option. Now maybe not. But did it uninstall other applications also? Only 16.04 may be based on python3.5 with 2.7 available. Your 14.04 should be based on 2.7 with 3.x available. Currently running 16.04, so cannot check exact version.

Comment: Well I also thought that 14.04 depended on 2.7, that's why I thought I could remove 3.4 freely in the first place. However, I can't sudo apt-get install, in the stackoverflow thread someone suggested that my apt-get has been affected as well, so I'm not sure how should I proceed. I did not remove any other thing, only the python3.4 folders in usr/lib and usr/local/lib